# computeArea() in node.js using the array of points

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, npm

I need to calculate the area of the polygon having points on node.js

[[55.874, -4.282],[55.875, -4.292],[55.875, -4.290),[55.876, -4.290],[55.876, -4.291],[55.874, -4.291]]

google maps geometry spherical, not present in npm.

but I found github.com/NotWoods/spherical-geometry-js
where I can use computeArea function but I have to pass each coordinate like points: new google.maps.LatLng(55.874, -4.282)

but I didn't find the npm module to make like: new google.maps.LatLng(55.874, -4.282)

in node.js

Comment: That's link to github has a class `LatLng` just parse your array and convert.. eg..  something like `const points = theArray.map((b) => new LatLng(b[0], b[1]));`

Comment: @Keith I didn't understand that how can I create the instance of LatLng as in your comment.can you please give a small example for this.I will be very much thankful.

Comment: I think you should be able to get the LatLng class like -> `import LatLng from 'spherical-geometry-js/latlng'`  I'd post and answer but it's likely just to get down-voted,.  Not like it matters now as in 24hrs my account will be gone.. :)